# .NET ConfigurationErrorsException

Tags: .net, appdomain

I seem to get the exception:

```
ConfigurationErrorsException was unhandled:
Configuration system failed to initialize
```

When I call `Dns.GetHostName()`

It seems to be linked to when the `AppDomain` is being unloaded.  The exception only seems to come up when the `AppDomain` is unloaded/reloaded.  I don't know if there is a race condition where the `AppDomain` is being unloaded before it can be fully loaded... however I've put `SyncRoots` around the loading and unloading, but this hasn't helped.

Comment: What is the InnerException and stack trace?

Comment: I can't tell... I get: `Unable to evaluate because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack.` However, my project is not set to optimize.

Comment: If you step out or unwind the call stack, you should be able to get details.

Comment: It just closes when I try to step into/out of it.